# Exchanging Public Keys in .NET

Tags: c#, encryption, key, private, public

I am trying to exchange the public keys of a client and a server.

As soon as I make the request from the client and send the key to the server, the following exception is being raised by the server:

[image]

The exception is an HttpRequestValidationException.  It says that a potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (contents of public key).

What does this exception mean?  Why am I not allowed to exchange public keys using normal POST requests?

I tried embedding the public key into a JObject, yet the same exception is raised.  How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like an overzealous (and IMO misguided) XSS protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I had to introduce this line into my web.config file on the server:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: +0: generally not a good idea. Sending binary data as Base64 would be safer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't think the key is binary data. It's XML.